# Create an event / plugin for Composer

Tags: php, composer-php

I developed a portable WebServer and I'm creating a portable console too, to use Composer.

I have a problem. I need to create a plugin to add additional behavior to Composer.

I need that when downloading any package with Composer, it edits the composer.json "scripts" of that package, so that it works on the portable console.

When downloading Laravel, for example:

Original composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "php -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

composer.json edited by the plugin:

```
{
    "name": "laravel/laravel",
    ...
    "scripts": {
        "post-root-package-install": [
            "F:/portable_php_path/php.exe -r \"file_exists('.env') || copy('.env.example', '.env');\""
        ],
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```

- Note that a physical path has been generated for php.exe, because in the portable version it can be in any path.

(My question is for the creation of the composer plugin. I have no problem editing the composer.json with PHP.)

I read the tutorial for creating a plugin on the composer site, but I was confused. (https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/plugins.md)

If there is another way to do that, it's also interesting. I accept other suggestions and ideas.

Thanks to anyone who can help.

[Sorry my bad english]

Comment: What have you tried? What specific problem(s) did you encounter and would like to have help with?

Comment: Have you noticed that only the "scripts" section of the root package is executed? So it should be defined on application level which commandline/whatever script is executed (in your case which php executable is used). e.g. The scripts section of Laravel should not be executed if it is a dependency.see https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/scripts.md#what-is-a-script-

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you can have a plugin implements `PluginInterface` and `EventSubscriberInterface`

```
public static function getSubscribedEvents()
{
    return [
        'post-package-install' => 'onPostPackageInstall'
        // hook  post-package-install using onPostPackageInstall method
    ];
}

public function onPostPackageInstall(\Composer\Installer\PackageEvent $event)
{
    $vendorDir = $event->getComposer()->getConfig()->get('vendor-dir') . '/';

    /** @var InstallOperation $item */
    foreach ($event->getOperations() as $item) {

        $packageInstalled = $item->getPackage()->getName();
        // do any thing with the package name like `laravel/laravel`
        //You can now edit the composer.json file 

        echo $vendorDir . $packageInstalled . '/composer.json';

    }

}
```